# add class to image link

Tags: image, cakephp, hyperlink

I have the following cakephp code

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('products/'.$product['Product']['picture'],array('url'=>'/img/products/thumb.big.'.$product['Product']['picture'])); ?>
```

The above code produce the follwoing html:

```
<a href="/oscar-demo/cakephp/img/products/thumb.big.hs_2010_13_a_1920x1200_wallpaper.jpg">
    <img alt="" src="/oscar-demo/cakephp/img/products/hs_2010_13_a_1920x1200_wallpaper.jpg">
</a>
```

But I want to add a class in `a`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use image inside a link:

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('products/'.$product['Product']['picture']), '/img/products/thumb.big.'.$product['Product']['picture'], array('class' => 'css-class', 'escape' => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created class deleteImg in style.css and linked image in that class and simply applied class to that link.

echo $this->Html->link('',array('controller'=>'Mycont','action'=>'deletepic',$id),array('confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete the image?','class'=>'deleteImg'));

Answer (score -1):

why dont you consult the book?
it actually contains a lot of examples for exactly this use case:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link